# How to calculate the size of an element depending of resolution?

Tags: android, html, css

I'm making a website and with a 40px of height navbar and when I see it in a mobile device (Galaxy S4) it looks a bit smaller than in my screen (iMac 21.5"). I have the

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0;">
```

line in the HTML and it looks fine but not the exact same size as in my computer, this is not a problem in this case but I would like to know how to calculate the size an elemente will have in other screens, because it looks that 40px in my mobile are smaller than 40px in my computer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most mobile have greater than 1024px wide screens. Try use percetage and read this you might have a problem with viewport.

http://blog.javierusobiaga.com/stop-using-the-viewport-tag-until-you-know-ho